# Detect user declines permission for RPScreenRecorder recording request

Tags: swift, video, screen, recording

I'm using RPScreenRecorder to record screen. When the recording starts, RPScreenRecorder presents users with a permission request alert dialog. However, it seems that there is no easy way to detect if a user declines the permission request. The following is my code snippet.

```
 @objc func startRecording(width: Int32, height: Int32) -> Bool {
            var res : Bool = true
            .......
            
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
               recorder.startCapture(handler: 
                  (cmSampleBuffer, rpSampleType, error) in guard error == nil else {
    
                        if let rpError = error as NSError?, rpError.code == -5801 {
                //  if let rpError = error as NSError?, rpError.code == PRRecordingErrorCode.userDeclined.rawValue                                                                 //The user declined application recording permission
                           print("User declined application recording permission.")
                           res = false
                           }
                           return;
                         }
        return  Bool(res)
   }
```

It seems that the error code -5801 doesn't get populated under `startRecording`. Appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The `startCapture` method takes two blocks: `handler`, and `completion`. The completion block provides an optional `Error` parameter. If the user denies the recording, the completion block is called with an error representing the denial.

Code similar to the following can be used to check for this:

```swift
recorder.startCapture(handler: { buffer, type, error in
    print("capture started")
    if let error {
        // Not reached when the user denies the recording
        print("capture start error: \(error)")
    }
}) { error in
    print("capture completion")
    if let error = error as? NSError, let code = RPRecordingErrorCode(rawValue: error.code) {
        switch code {
            case .userDeclined:
                print("User declined")
            default:
                print("capture completion error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

See the list of error codes in the documentation for [`RPRecordingErrorCode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rprecordingerrorcode).

Comment: @jdevp2 - Did this answer your question?